# Why doesn't my Javascript if else work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I've been messing around with this mobile friendly navigation menu, and for some reason my menu will open (JS IF statement), but not close (JS ELSE statement.  So I'm stuck as to why it is opening but not closing?

P.S. I'm new to JavaScript, so it might be something simple that I over looked, thanks!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}


function navChange() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNav").style.height
    if (x = "0%"){
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    } else {
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
    z-index: 12;
}

.bar1, .bar2 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, 0px) ;
    background-color: gray;
}

.change .bar2 {
    transform: translate(1px, -10px) rotate(45deg);
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this), navChange()">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time and energy!

Comment: Why the downvote for the OP? It is a common fault to happen when new to javascript, and I believe not all answers here on SO serve as an answer or could not define why exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything EasyBB said was true, but here's an example on how it can be done cleanly:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}


function navChange() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNav").clientHeight; // Use clientHeight to get the actual height, ignoring style rules. //.style.height
    if (x == "0"){ // == to compare, = here would set the value, so x would always equal 0.
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    } else {
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0"; //No reason to use percentage here, as 0% =0px.
    }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
    z-index: 12;
}

.bar1, .bar2 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, 0px) ;
    background-color: gray;
}

.change .bar2 {
    transform: translate(1px, -10px) rotate(45deg);
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this), navChange()">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much for giving finished code, I'm new to JavaScript and that really helped!!!

Comment: No problem, pay close attention to the notes I've added ( after the // on the line)  and you'll see what I did.

Answer (score 5):

The reasoning for the errors that I see is for one you are doing assignment in your conditions.

```
a = 15;
b = 10;
if(a = b) alert("hello world");
```

a now is now `10`, because we used assignment instead of testing for equality which would look like.

```
if( a == b)
```

Also you are testing the style property which looks like you are setting through CSS and `style.height` will not return what you are looking for. You will need to test PX or what have you.

```
var height =  window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("element")).height;
var height = parseInt(height,10);
if( height > 1510 ) {
    //do whatever
}
```

Comment: How can I use PX when my height is 100%?

Comment: You'll have to store the initial PX value with JavaScript. Per se when the page loads.

`var originalHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("element")).height;`

Then we can test `height == originalHeight` etc.

Comment: If you look at my code, the height that is changing is CSS height.

Comment: Yes you are using a CSS class to change the height, meaning `style` will not work. Only and only if the style property exists on the element will the browser compile that request correctly. i.e. `<div style="height:100%"></div>`

Comment: Ok, I see.  Thanks for all your help!  I accepted the other answer because it had a finished JavaScript, and because I'm new that is really helpful.  Thank you again for all your effort!